# Setting Json data from webservice in datatables

Tags: jquery, json, api, web-services, datatables

I have to set data which is returned from a webservice into a datatable HTML table. code is given. I have tried to set columns but this is not working showing "No data available in table".

**HTML**

```
     <table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                    <thead class="scrollmenu">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sr.#</th>
                            <th>Reference</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Value Date</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Transaction Type</th>
                            <th>Sender Bic</th>
                            <th>Receiver Bic</th>
                            <th>Receiver Account</th>
                            <th>Sender Account</th>
                            <th>Sender</th>
                            <th>Receiver</th>
                            <th>Payer's Participant</th>
                            <th>Beneficiary Participant</th>
                            <th>Creation Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var datefrom = $('#dateFrom').val();
    var dateto = $('#dateTo').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DashBoard/fetchDataDetails?flag="+flag+"&from=" + datefrom + "&" + "to=" + dateto,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data.length > 0) {
                debugger;
                var abc = data;
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "system_reference_no" },
                        { "data": "mt_type" },
                        { "data": "system_refdate" },
                        { "data": "system_refamount" },
                        { "data": "TransType_Code" },
                        { "data": "sender" },
                        { "data": "receiver" },
                        { "data": "receiver_account" },
                        { "data": "sender_account" },
                        { "data": "sender_bic" },
                        { "data": "receiver_bic" },
                        { "data": "sender_bank" },
                        { "data": "receiver_bank" },
                        { "data": "creation_date" },
                    ]
                });

            }
            //  processingGif(false);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // processingGif(false);
        }



    });
```

But This is not working. I have tried different options but can't get it to work. Need HELP.

Comment: You need to debug the AJAX request being made to `DashBoard/fetchDataDetails`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to the DataTable using [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   "data": data 
});
```